How to stop background music when playing a video in React Native and resume it after pausing?
I'm developing an app using React Native, and I'm facing an issue with controlling background music when a video is played. Specifically, I want to mimic Instagram's behavior where:
The background music stops completely when a video starts playing in non-silent mode.
The background music resumes when the video is paused.
Currently, I'm using react-native-video to handle video playback, it stops the background music when i play the video but never play the background music again when i pause the video.
i tried to use expo-av's Video component, but it lowers the volume of background music,
i want to pause background music and play it again when i pause video.

What do you mean with background music?

like spotify or other music apps playing in background.

whats your code right now to get the background music to stop playing ? Is this for iOS or Android ?
